# É possível incluir um arquivo JavaScript dentro de outro arquivo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

É possível incluir um arquivo JavaScript dentro de outro arquivo JavaScript?

Semelhante ao `@import` em CSS ou ao `include` do PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você só poderá incluir um script em uma página HTML. sabendo disto você possui algumas soluções para "simular" a inclusão pelo javascript, como seria isso?

No meu arquivo index.html possuo meu arquivo scripts.js, nele eu gostaria de carregar outras duas. clientes.js e produtos.js então eu faço assim:

**Com javascript:**

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'cliente.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

**Com jQuery:**

```
$.getScript("produtos.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");
});
```

Existem outras maneiras mas elas são apenas formas diferentes de incluir o javascript no html seja de forma assíncrona ou não.

[Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Porém adicionando o `script` ao HTML não vai incluir o script dentro do outro script – o script adicionado vai ser executado em um escopo global.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai exatamente, por isto é importante ter um cuidado a mais na hora de realizar esta  inclusão,  e outra, sempre ter o cuidado de evitar conflito encapsulando os métodos e variáveis.

Answer (score 2):

Possível é, porém esta não é uma funcionalidade nativa.

Não existem diretivas @import, #include, include() ou algo parecido para Javascript.

O que é possível fazer (eu considero gambiarra) é criar um elemento  através de código Javascript e atribuir ao conteúdo deste elemento o conteúdo de um outro arquivo.

Não recomendo.

Answer (score 1):

Allan, como o Bruno já mencionou, atualmente não existe uma implementação nativa que faça o include de outros arquivos `JS`. porém você pode definir os seus scripts como módulos e usar uma biblioteca `AMD` para gerenciar os seus scripts.

Eu diria que usar `AMD` no seu projeto pode ser especialmente vantajoso se estiver desenvolvendo uma aplicação `SPA`, mas nada impede que utilize esta abordagem em uma aplicação multi-page.

Alguns exemplos de Blibiotecas AMD são:

- [`RequireJS`](http://requirejs.org)
- [`CurlJS`](https://github.com/cujojs/curl)

Segue um pequeno exemplo retirado do `Github` do `RequireJS`

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="app" src="lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note que no exemplo, ele apenas adicionou o `require.js` e informou o arquivo *.js que possui a configuração do AMD, no caso o `app.js`

**app.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
requirejs(['app/main']);
```

aqui ele definiu o caminho para os scripts, no caso a pasta `lib` e um `path` para a pasta `app`, e começou a execução do arquivo `app/main.js`

**app/main.js**

```
define(function (require) {
    var messages = require('./messages');
    var print = require('print');

    print(messages.getHello());
});
```

aqui ele informou que o script possui duas dependerias, `app/messages.js` e `lib/print.js`, neste caso ele vai esperar que os dois `scripts` sejam executados para poder continuar.

**lib/print.js**

```
define(function () {
    return function print(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    };
});
```

aqui não tem muito segredo, temos apenas uma função sem dependências.

**app/messages.js**

```
define(function () {
    return {
        getHello: function () {
            return 'Hello World';
        }
    };
});
```

mesma coisa aqui, porém é retornado um objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Não enquanto não implementam um método ou statement. Está "ok" que é possível, em JavaScript:

- 1 . criar um elemento `script`;
- 2 . atribuir o `src` do `script`;
- 3 . adicionar o `script` para o HTML;

Assim o conteúdo de um arquivo externo é requisicionado, então depois é interpretado e executado pelo navegador, porém é executado em um escopo global, ou seja, o `JavaScript` não vai estar incluído dentro do outro `JavaScript`. É uma solução, mas não como você quer.

Comment: Eu não diria que "nunca será possível", mas sim que é "muito improvável". Se a questão é porque a linguagem trabalha com um interpretador e precisaria de um processo de compilação e análise para isso, bem, o próprio ES6 possui modules que trabalham com análise estática (algo parecido com o que seria necessário para fazer um #include no JS).

Então caso o time que cuida da especificação do ECMAScript queira colocar isso, é possível com os recursos atuais, mas como eu disse, acho muito improvável (e nada útil, nunca precisei usar)

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Eu concordo um pouco, mas se forem adicionar esse tal de #include não vai funcionar muito bem porque o arquivo declarado tem que carregar e não vai executar no mesmo escopo. No CSS até faz mais sentido o `@include`, mesmo tendo que carregar, pois na linguagem não há escopos.

Comment: Não exatamente, isso depende de como eles implementariam, nada impede de eles implementarem de uma maneira que o escopo seja resolvido (ou não). Estamos falando de uma feature não implementada, não podemos supor tais limitações se ao olharmos no ponto de vista do compilador/interpretador isso pode ser possível... mas seria trabalhoso demais e como eu disse, acho desnecessário.

Answer (score -1):

É perfeitamente possivel, crie um arquivo 'list.js' e faça dessa forma:

```
import('assets/exemple.min.js')
import('assets/exemple2.min.js')
import('assets/exemple3.min.js')
import('assets/exemple4.min.js')
.then(module => {
        module.loadPageInto(main);
      });
```

Seus arquivos carregaram normalmente como em uma tag `<script>`, você pode encontrar outras informações na documentação, acesse: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import